# Unexpected non-void return value in void function - Swift 4 (Firebase, Firestore)

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

So I want a Boolean function that returns true or false depending on whether the given email exists for a user in the `users` collection.

However if I try and return `True` or `False` within the `getDocuments` call I get the error: `non-void return value in void function`

```
func checkUserWith(email: String) -> Bool
{
    let usersDB = database.collection("users")
    usersDB.whereField("email", isEqualTo: email).getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in

        if error != nil
        {
            print("Error: \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "")")
            return false
        }

        for document in (snapshot?.documents)! {
            if document.data()["email"]! as! String == email {
                return true
            }
        }

        return false
    }
}
```

I have a feeling it is because I am trying to return a boolean within the Firestore call which is expecting a different variable type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the firebase operation gives you a callback closure, and the calls made asynchronously, I believe it wont be possible for you to directly return from closures. However, you can return an escaping closure indicating true or false as follows...

```
func checkUserWith(email: String, completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void)
{
    let usersDB = database.collection("users")
    usersDB.whereField("email", isEqualTo: email).getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in

        if error != nil
        {
            print("Error: \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "")")
            completion(false)
        }

        for document in (snapshot?.documents)! {
            if document.data()["email"]! as! String == email {
                completion(true)
                return
            }
        }

        completion(false)
    }
}
```

Then when you call this method:

```
checkUserWith(email: emailHere) { (isSucceeded) in
    if isSucceeded {
        //it exists, do something
    } else {
        //user does not exist, do something else
    }
}
```

Comment: Not able to return that variable unless it is outside of `usersDB.whereField("email", isEqualTo: email).getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in`

Unfortunately it will return before that callback finishes.

Comment: You are right. I advised a different approach by editing my answer, can you check it?

Comment: It works! I have made some small tweaks but more or less spot on. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Thanks for editing, I accepted changes, happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Your function should return `Bool` instead of `String`.

Comment: Haha, I wrote it out wrong on the question. I am returning a Bool in the project. Corrected it

Answer (score 0):

change function return type String to Bool

```
func checkUserWith(email: String) -> Bool
{
    let usersDB = database.collection("users")
    usersDB.whereField("email", isEqualTo: email).getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in

        if error != nil
        {
            print("Error: \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "")")
            return false
        }

        for document in (snapshot?.documents)! {
            if document.data()["email"]! as! String == email {
                return true
            }
        }

        return false
    }
}
```