# Dictionary not adding values retrieved from Firestore

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, closures

I am retrieving data from firebase firestore(not auth) and want to store it in a dictionary. As it loops through the documents it should pull each key and its respective value and store it in a dictionary. However, it does not do this. The code is below:

```
extension HomeViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 50
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 50
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = JobListingTable.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "JobListing", for: indexPath as IndexPath)
        var data = fetchPostData()
        print(data)
        return cell
    }

    func fetchPostData() -> [String: Any] {
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        var dataArray = ["1": "1" as Any]
        db.collection("posts").getDocuments { (query, err) in
            if err != nil{
                print("error retrieving data")
            } else {
                print("worked")
                for documents in (query?.documents)!{
                    let dataUser = documents.dictionaryWithValues(forKeys: ["HirerUID"])
                    for dictObjects in dataUser {
                        dataArray[dictObjects.key] = dictObjects.value
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return dataArray
    }
}
```

It only prints out a dictionary with the dummy values over and over until it stops looping through.

Comment: Data is retrieved from Firestore asynchronously, since it may take some time before the data comes back from the server. Instead of making the app wait for the data, your main code (including your `return dataArray`) continues to run. And the when the data is available in the client your closure gets called. This means that any code that needs the data from the server must be *inside* the closure, or be called from there. See for an example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54129443/unexpected-non-void-return-value-in-void-function-swift-4-firebase-firestore/54129647#54129647